# ¿Cómo se sale de Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Me he quedado enganchado en Vim y no puedo salir. Me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> ```
> type :quit<Enter> to quit VIM
> ```

Pero cuando lo escribo me aparece en el bloque de texto. ¿Cómo se sale entonces de Vim?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Presiona la tecla <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Con ello, vim entra en el modo de comandos.

Luego, puedes teclear una de las siguientes opciones:

- `:q`  para salir (versión corta de `:quit`)
- `:q!` para salir sin guardar (versión corta de `:quit!`)
- `:wq` para escribir y salir (think write and quit)
- `:wq!` para escribir y salir incluso si el fichero tiene solo permiso de lectura (si no tiene permiso de escritura, fuerza la escritura)
- `:x`  para escribir y salir (parecido a `:wq`, pero no escribe si no hay cambios)
- `:qa` para salir de todas las pantallas (versión corta de `:quitall`)

Cuando presionas `:`, aparecerá un `:` en la parte inferior de la pantalla.

Para obtener más ayuda de Vim, teclea <kbd>Esc</kbd>`:help`<kbd>Return</kbd> y obtendrás todas las respuestas en un tutorial muy aseadito.

Comment: Adaptado de [How to exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828573/1983854).

Answer (score 7):

Los comandos empezados en dos puntos son los más conocidos a la hora de salir de vim.

Sin embargo, también hay un par de comandos que que no requieren de
dos puntos previos, aunque sí requieren estar en modo normal (hay que presionar <kbd>Esc</kbd> si se está en otro modo). Esos comandos son:

- `ZZ`  Salir guardando
- `ZQ`  Salir sin guardar