# como arreglar el bash de mi mac

Tags: bash, shell, rutas, macos

estaba intentando configurar mysql en mi mac y ejecute los comandos de esta pagina: http://www.elwebmaster.com/articulos/instalando-mysql-en-mac-os-x.

y mi problema es este[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que puedo hacer?

Comment: No está claro qué has hecho exactamente (la página que enlazas son instrucciones variadas para instalar MySQL). Supongo que en algún momento has añadido instrucciones a `~/.bash_profile`, y quizás equivocaste la sintaxis. ¿Puedes mostrar (o si es muy largo proporcionar un enlace a un pastebin) el contenido del fichero `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Esta linea en concreto fue la que provoco el error:   
echo ‘export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH’ >> ~/.bash_profile

Después de introducirla me genero el error de la imagen, podrías ayudarme a arreglarlo? xD

Comment: He escrito una respuesta explicando por qué funcionó mal, cómo tendría que haberse hecho, y cómo arreglarlo ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Al ver el tutorial, al parecer esta sentencia es la que ha causado lo que se indica

```
echo ‘export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH’ >> ~/.bash_profile
```

El comando no es `‘export` es `export`

Por tanto la sentencia debería ir escrita así

```
echo export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Lo verifique en la terminal también

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se ingresa `export` está incorporado en el `shell`

```
$ type export
export is a shell builtin
```

En cambio `‘export` no está incorporado en el `shell`

```
$ type ‘export
-bash: type ‘export: not found
```

Esto quiere decir que el `PATH` es irrelevante, por ejemplo cuando coloco `echo $PATH` en mi terminal obtengo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> No obstante lo anterior, una solución es **remover cualquier caracter escória o mal escrito** antes del comando `export` o en general para cualquier comando.

En general, se recomienda seguir los siguientes comandos para identificar qué archivos tienen el caracter mal escrito en el respectivo comando ejecutado mediante las constantes definidas en el `BASH`:

```
PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xlic ""  7>trace.out
grep '[Caracter Escoria]comando' trace.out
```

Para nuestro caso la última línea sería

```
grep '‘export' trace.out
```

## Solución

Una vez identificado *el fichero* con las sentencias de arriba dónde se encuentra `‘export`,- en este caso ya lo indicó @abulafia es el fichero `~/.bash_profile`- puedes entrar a él mediante `vim` en el terminal, te recomiendo leer esto primero [¿Cómo se sale de vim?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73100/c%C3%B3mo-se-sale-de-vim)

Escribe esto en el terminal

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Con las direccionales ve hasta la línea donde aparece `‘export` y borra su caracter `‘`, hacer lo propio con el caracter `’` de `$PATH’`.

Luego sal de `vim` con <kbd>esc</kbd> y escribe `:q` `(guardar los cambios y salir)`

Si bien esta forma es sencilla porque es manual, hay que tener cuidado al momento de borrar. Lo uso básicamente cuando tengo que realizar alguna edición básica de un archivo `.lua`, `.R`, `.txt`, etc antes de subirlo a `github` o para leer contenidos sin tener que entrar al **Xcode, Visual Studio o RStudio**.

Si borraste algo que no debías sal de `vim` pero sin guardar <kbd>esc</kbd> `:q!` y vuelve a intentarlo.

Comment: En efecto esta fue la linea que genero este error
echo ‘export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH’ >> ~/.bash_profile

Pero aun no me queda claro que debo hacer para que no aparezca siempre ese error en el bash :'(

Comment: Una forma es con `vim` lo he incluido en mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Por dar un poco más de contexto a la causa del problema, el tutorial que seguiste te pide en un momento que ejecutes lo siguiente:

```
echo ‘export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH’ >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Cuando tendría que haber dicho esto otro:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Nota la diferencia en el tipo de comillas usadas. La versión "mala" usa comillas tipográficas, `‘así’` que no son caracteres ASCII estándar (además de que la comilla de cierre es diferente de la de apertura). La versión "buena" usa el apóstrofe ASCII, `'asi'`.

Posiblemente haya sido el editor usado por el autor de la página quien la haya jugado una mala pasada. Por ejemplo, Microsoft Word tiene la "costumbre" de cambiarte las comillas ASCII por las tipográficas. Seguramente le ha ocurrido eso.

El caso es que no basta con quitar las comillas como parte del comando `echo` antes mencionado, pues si lo haces la variable `$PATH` quedaría "desprotegida", y sería expandida por el shell. Me explico.

Compara lo que sale cuando haces cuando pones las comillas:

```
$ echo '$PATH'
$PATH
```

con cuando no las pones:

```
$ echo $PATH  
 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

En el primer caso te muestra literalmente el texto `$PATH` (sin las comillas rodeándolo), mientras que en el segundo te muestra *el valor* de la variable. Esto es así porque el *shell* ha sustituido `$PATH` por su valor, operación llamada *expansión* de la variable. Las comillas simples le dicen al shell que no realize esa expansión (y son eliminadas automáticamente del resultado).

Así pues, las comillas eran importantes en el comando, pero debían ser las correctas.

Al haber usado comillas incorrectas, habrás volcado al final del fichero `~/.bash_profile` una línea que comienza por `‘export`, y ya que tal comando es desconocido, produce un error.

Para corregir el problema basta que edites `~/.bash_profile` y elimines esas líneas que comienzan por `‘export`. Una vez eliminadas, vuelve a ejecutar el comando `echo` con las comillas correctas, o si prefieres y aprovechando que ya tienes el editor abierto, escribe tú mismo a mano al final de ese fichero la línea:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

que es la que tendría que haber aparecido de haber ejecutado bien el comando.

Comment: Buen punto @abulafia con lo de las comillas simples `'` incluso si uno coloca en el terminal `$ type 'export'`se obtendrá `export is a shell builtin` pero si olvido colocar la `'` al final `$ type 'export` me veré forzado a salir con `ctrl+c`