# ¿Cómo salir de Vi?

Tags: vi

quiero salir del editor de texto Vi sin apagar la consola. Apreto <kbd>esc</kbd> y luego <kbd>:q</kbd>, pero me devuelve a cada rato. Alguien podría darme una manita [image: lin]

Comment: Ya presione intro y me devuelve a escribir en el editor y yo quiero volver a la consola, se que sirve apretar control z pero yo quiero cerrar el editor de texto no dejarlo abierto

Comment: Creo que ya hay preguntas sobre eso en el sitio. De todas maneras, para salirte del editor VI, presiona la combinación Shift + Z + Z, o Shift + Z + Q para no guardar los cambios

Comment: `Esc : q!`  Para salir sin guardar.   `Esc : wq` para salir guardando

Comment: Es lo que buscaba, gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo se sale de Vim?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73100/c%c3%b3mo-se-sale-de-vim)